# Dayjs return number instead of relative word with `.form`

Tags: javascript, dayjs

There are plugin on dayjs ([`relativeTime`](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/relative-time)) that will returning **human readable string** instead of number. Is there any way to return just number?

something  like these

```js
dayjs('2020-07-1').from(dayjs('2020-07-9')) // -8
dayjs('2020-07-1').from(dayjs('2020-07-1')) // 0
dayjs('2020-07-11').from(dayjs('2020-07-9')) // 2
```

Comment: Use moment.js instead

Comment: @chiliNUT tooo big for me ~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Working Code !!***

Using `diff()` method from `dayjs` library with `'day'` as a second parameter

```js
console.log(dayjs('2020-07-1').diff('2020-07-9', 'day'));     // -8
console.log(dayjs('2020-07-1').diff('2020-07-1', 'day'));     // 0
console.log(dayjs('2020-07-11').diff('2020-07-9', 'day'));    // 2
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.8.29/dayjs.min.js" integrity="sha512-APVsMirhHF2o3YdCSwYonM7egfT589pTqyoy5hIzEbs9sAGJSbEI6ssXUwngHjaq4V/GmmmpgqrcLSvsO+gsJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

***NOTE: `'day'` can be replaced with `'d`' which being a shorthand***

Answer (score 1):

Without `dayjs` I can suggest simple way to get your desired result like below.

```js
function getDayDifference(from, to) {
  let diffInMilliseconds = new Date(from) - new Date(to);
  // divide with (1000*60*60*24) to get difference in days.
  let days = Math.round(diffInMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  console.log(days);
  return days;
}

getDayDifference('2020-07-1', '2020-07-9'); // -8
getDayDifference('2020-07-1', '2020-07-1'); // 0
getDayDifference('2020-07-11', '2020-07-9'); // 2
```

---

Or alternatively you can define your own extension method for `dayjs` with `dayjs.prototype.getDayDifference = function(to) {...}`. You can check it below.

```js
dayjs.prototype.getDayDifference = function(to) {
  //86400000 = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
  return Math.round((this.$d - to.$d) / 86400000);
}

console.log(dayjs('2020-07-1').getDayDifference(dayjs('2020-07-9'))); // -8
console.log(dayjs('2020-07-1').getDayDifference(dayjs('2020-07-1'))); // 0
console.log(dayjs('2020-07-11').getDayDifference(dayjs('2020-07-9'))); // 2
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.8.29/dayjs.min.js" integrity="sha512-APVsMirhHF2o3YdCSwYonM7egfT589pTqyoy5hIzEbs9sAGJSbEI6ssXUwngHjaq4V/GmmmpgqrcLSvsO+gsJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```